# css vertical divider inbetween col bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put a divider inbetween the two divs but I can't find a solution without putting the class tag in the div area which I don't want to do.

What I want to do is something like this. [Jsfiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/ut8dgbxz/1/)

```
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="box1"></div>
```

Comment: Do you want it divided vertically or horizontally? You could explain more what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/ut8dgbxz/2/

Comment: @Keammoort I did mention vertical divider in the title. if you increase the html result of the fiddler you'll see the content is divided equally not stacked together.

Comment: @MrNew As like this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/ut8dgbxz/3/

Comment: @RohitAzad Yes something like that but is it possible not to put the divider class in the content div?

Comment: @MrNew Have a look at my answer now.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Where? if the one when you wrapped the content in <div class="divider"> I replied to that one.

Comment: @MrNew checkout my solution, is that what you want?

Comment: @MrNew http://jsbin.com/luvasuqici/edit?output Is this what you are looking for buddy?

Comment: @MrNew A better version: http://jsbin.com/fimemukofa/1/edit?output

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear in the sense of vertical or horizontal divider! So, for horizontal divider, that is a line that is sleeping or parallel to the floor, instead of `div.divider` use:

```
<hr />
```

This is the right way, which is called horizontal rule.

**Snippet**

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo a quisquam earum accusamus iusto quos sunt incidunt laudantium ratione unde veritatis soluta fuga cum hic odit asperiores accusantium nulla libero.</div>
      <hr />
      <div class="col-md-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expliabo a quisquam earum accusamus iusto quos sunt incidunt laudantium ratione unde veritatis soluta fuga cum hic odit asperiores accusantium nulla libero.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If it is supposed to be vertical one, i.e., the standing one, use this way:

**Snippet**

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css");
.divider {border-left: 2px solid #ccc; padding-left: 5px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo a quisquam earum accusamus iusto quos sunt incidunt laudantium ratione unde veritatis soluta fuga cum hic odit asperiores accusantium nulla libero.</div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="divider">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expliabo a quisquam earum accusamus iusto quos sunt incidunt laudantium ratione unde veritatis soluta fuga cum hic odit asperiores accusantium nulla libero.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Make sure you do the columns this way: Use two `.col-md-6` for equal width columns. And then use the CSS:

```css
.divider {border-left: 2px solid #ccc; padding-left: 5px; margin-left: -5px;}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    Some content here.
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="divider">
        Some content here.
    </div>
</div>
```

**Snippet**

```css
.divider {border-left: 2px solid #ccc; padding-left: 3px; margin-left: -5px; height: 50px; float: left;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">Hello</div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">Hello</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This replaces the margin displaced with the padding. And then you can use it anywhere.

**Important Note:** Never use the divider with `.col-*-*` classes as the layout might get screwed up in the responsiveness.

Comment: I need a vertical divider, if you increase the html result of the fiddler you'll see the content is divided equally not stacked together.

Comment: @MrNew Have a look now!

Comment: Is this the only to have a vertical divider? Wrap the content in divider class? Also yes that's why I said I don't want to put divider class in col- class. Isn't there a way to have it like the structure in my JSfiddler?

Comment: @MrNew You can do the same what you did in your fiddle with my code. As it is fine. Have a look?

Comment: @MrNew Added a snippet.

Comment: Ah I just saw this and I have tried that before I posted here the problem is that the height shouldn't be fixed so it would stretch with the content. height auto and 100% didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a divideer you can give right border to the first div as following:

```
.col-xs-6:first-child //can be md as well{
    border-right:1px solid;
}
```

See the fiddle: "http://jsfiddle.net/ut8dgbxz/4/"

Comment: I guess I could use that but I have nested cols though so I think that's gonna be a problem. That's why I separate the divider class and not put it in the content div.

Comment: You can create a new class and give border right to that class. Add it to divs which will have a divider else don't add that class

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you don't want to put extra html element in there. What about this solution (this will work with many columns, not just two):

```
.col-md-6:nth-child(odd) {
    border-right: 1px dotted grey;
}

.col-md-6:nth-child(even) {
    border-right: none;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo a quisquam earum accusamus iusto quos sunt incidunt laudantium ratione unde veritatis soluta fuga cum hic odit asperiores accusantium nulla libero.</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expliabo a quisquam earum accusamus iusto quos sunt incidunt laudantium ratione unde veritatis soluta fuga cum hic odit asperiores accusantium nulla libero.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmu3Lfzh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Now try to this way

```css
.box1{
 width:50%;
  float:left;
  background:gray;
}
.container {overflow:hidden;}
.divider{
    position:relative;
}
.divider:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    right:50%;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    border-right:dotted 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container divider"><div class="box1 ">Hello</div>
<div class="box1">Hello  two </div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `border-left` using the sibling selector to act as the vertical divider. *This is not dependent on the number of columns in the row* so you can use it independently.

```css
.dividers {
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
}
.dividers [class^=col] + [class^=col] {
  /* To match all the classes prefixed with col and which has a sibling */
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 dividers">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo a quisquam earum accusamus iusto quos sunt incidunt laudantium ratione unde veritatis soluta fuga cum hic odit asperiores accusantium nulla libero.</div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expliabo a quisquam earum accusamus iusto quos sunt incidunt laudantium ratione unde veritatis soluta fuga cum hic odit asperiores accusantium nulla libero.</div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo a quisquam earum accusamus iusto quos sunt incidunt laudantium ratione unde veritatis soluta fuga cum hic odit asperiores accusantium nulla libero.</div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expliabo a quisquam earum accusamus iusto quos sunt incidunt laudantium ratione unde veritatis soluta fuga cum hic odit asperiores accusantium nulla libero.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would work but if you have 3 col- or more then you have to duplicate the dividers sucha s divider1-2-3 which is not a good approach, right?

Comment: Certainly not! I have updated my code for your problem. Will that help? :)

Comment: how can I make it 100% to the div not the content? I put 100% and it didn't work. Because this looks weird http://jsfiddle.net/yna0p4nr/

Comment: If you want to put 100%, you need to set a height for the parent element as well. So it moves upwards until html element. http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/yna0p4nr/1/

You need to give a fixed height for `dividers` in this case in order to reduce the overflow.

Comment: @MrNew I have updated the solution to automatically calculate the height of the div. But it will only work for IE10+  and other major browsers if it is not your problem. You can have a fallback for older browsers by having a fixed height for the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this kind:

```css
.container{
    background:#f5f5f5;
}
.col-md-6{
    border-bottom:1px solid grey;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    padding:0 0 10px 0;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo a quisquam earum accusamus iusto quos sunt incidunt laudantium ratione unde veritatis soluta fuga cum hic odit asperiores accusantium nulla libero.</div>
      
      <div class="col-md-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expliabo a quisquam earum accusamus iusto quos sunt incidunt laudantium ratione unde veritatis soluta fuga cum hic odit asperiores accusantium nulla libero.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="box1 divider"></div>
<div class="box1"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.divider {
  position: relative;
}

.divider:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  width: 1px;

  background-color: #000;
}
```

Just add an extra class to any div you want to be vertically divided then use this CSS. It removes the need for an extra element. This gives you more control when nesting grids

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the bootstrap .col-* classes, see my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzack5020/ooxn0vsr) for a way to put vertical dividers that adjust to the tallest column.

### Must view in full-screen for full effect

The borders are not used on mobile since the columns stack when viewed on a mobile platform.

```css
.row {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cols {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media(min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-4:not(:first-child), 
  .col-md-6:not(:first-child) {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
  }
  .col-md-4:not(:last-child),
  .col-md-6:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    margin-right: -1px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <h1>
    .col-md-6
  </h1>
  <hr>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-6 cols">
      <p>Enter some text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 cols">
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <h1>
    .col-md-4
  </h1>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-4 cols">
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 cols">
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cols col-md-4 cols">
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
      <p>Enter some more text here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```